# I want to verify a particular cell on all rows using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

This is the CSS path

row1: `body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div`

row6:
`body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[5]/div`

row14:
`body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[14]/div/div[5]/div`

It goes on till row 50

How do I write the code to verify the value of a cell on each and every row?
Please help

Comment: What does "verify the value of a cell on each and every row" mean?

Comment: On the webapp I am testing, I have a table with lot of details . I want to check that a particular column has the value "Received" on all rows.

Comment: And can you please re-look at your question and help us to understand what that means with regard to the rows and the CSS? Can you also read [ask]? And, what have you tried already? What code do you currently have?

Answer (score 2):

if you see, `div[1]`, becomes `div[6]` for `6th row` in your `xpath`.

**Sample code :**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) 
{
  string actual_Value = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/div[5]/div"));
  // assert here like or any other method based on your framework
  Assert.That(actual_Value.Text, "Received"); 
}
```